# NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php while trying to update

Tags: php, html, laravel, http

I'm trying to update a person in my table with form reuse from my create.blade.php. I've followed everything to the T from the Laracast videos up until episode 13, and have hit a large brick wall when trying to update.

It's giving me this error:

`NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
No query results for model [App\Models\ContactPerson]`

where my ContactPerson is the table in my database.

Here's the code I have so far,

**Routes**

```html
Route::post('create', 'ResourceController@store');

Route::resource('/pages', 'ResourceController');

Route::get('pages/{id}/edit', 'ResourceController@edit')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::patch('pages/{id}', 'ResourceController@update')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

**Resource Controller**

```html
use App\Models\ContactPerson;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Request;  


    public function store(Requests\CreateNewContactRequest $request)
    {
        ContactPerson::create($request->all());

        return redirect('resource');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
       $user = ContactPerson::findOrFail($id);

       return view('pages.edit')->with(compact('user'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

       //unset($request['_method']); A friend recommended doing this since he had the same problems, but it didn't work for me (MethodNotAllowed error)
       //unset($request['_token']);

       $user = ContactPerson::findOrFail($id);

       //ContactPerson::where('Contact_ID', $id->Id)->update($request->all()); 

        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect('pages.resource');
    }
}
```

**edit.blade.php (inside the pages folder)**

```html
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ResourceContoller@update', $user->id]]) !!}

      //I've tried setting it to where instead of 'action' it's 'url' => 'pages/edit', $user->id  but still not working.

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('first', 'First Name: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('First_Name', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        ...
```

**Route List** 
[image: routelist]

I've been stuck between this error and a `MethodNowAllowed` error because it didn't like the PUT/PATCH method for about 3-4 days now.  Any help would be great!

Comment: So far I do not see anything that has to do with PhpStorm... BTW -- what URL do you see in the browser when this does not work? Do all other URLs work (that do the same/similar actions)?

Comment: It goes to 'pages/edit' with the errors. This is the only update method I have so far, all the other methods work, create and views.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a spelling mistake in edit.blade.php , 
'action' => 'ResourceController@update'

Comment: Dileep, 

Thanks, it's correct in my code. I changed it on stack, because it's what Jeffrey Way had on his tutorial and I had it as `'url' => 'pages/edit`. I read somewhere on here that it could be a solution, it wasn't.